# C++ and Matlab ANN

Tags: c++, matlab, neural-network

I hope you can help me.

I'm writing a project divided in three parts:

1) a C++ program that collects 76 input for an Artificial Neural Network (Feedforwarding) developed in Matlab R2013a
2) the run of the ANN with the data collected by C++ program
3) the processing of the output produced by ANN

I've written the C++ program that produce the input for neurons.

What is, about you, the best way to pass these data to the ANN?

I imagine 2 ways:
1) the C++ invokes the Matlab script of the ANN
2) the Matlab ANN becomes a C++ program

If I issue the coder to generate the C++ program, I receive an error: "All entry-point files must be functions. RNA_Spedizioni.m is a script".

Could you help me?

Ciao!

PS: my email is gtnscebba@gmail.com

Answer (score 0):

add the following line at the beginning of `RNA_Spedzioni.m`

```
 function RNA_Spedzioni()
```

and re-run coder